# JFace FilteredTree not working

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a FilteredTree in my Eclipse (JFace) development, but this is not working.

```java
PatternFilter filter = new PatternFilter();
FilteredTree ftree = new FilteredTree(container, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.V_SCROLL, filter, false);
t= ftree.getViewer();
t.setContentProvider(new TreeFacetCP());
t.setLabelProvider(new TreeLp());
t.setInput(/*Reult Here*/); 
t.expandToLevel(3);
tree = t.getTree();
```

Showing result in the TreeViewer but when enter any text in the Text field, Treeviewer not filter.

Comment: Show us an [mcve]. We need something we can test.

Comment: A quick test of this guessing at the bits you haven't showed us works fine.